# Number of 5-digit positive integers divisible by 3 whose first digit is an even number?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

This exercise came up in my probability homework, but I do not know how to solve it with combinatorial methods. The only thing I could think of is seeing that the first 5-digit number with this property is 10,002 and the last one is 99,999. Thus, $10,002 + 3n = 99,999 \iff n = 29,999$, so there are $n + 1 = 30,000$ numbers with this property. How do I count the numbers with an even first digit only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As this is a homework in probability, I'd go another route. There is a total of 90000 5-digit numbers. Four out of possible nine first digits are even. Every third number is divisible by 3. So it's $90000\cdot \frac49 \cdot \frac13 \approx 13333$.

Comment: would this work when considering divisibility by an integer $k$ in a range $(a,b)$? Is it always right to apply the floor function to the end result? I'm wondering if there would be loss of accuracy at larger ranges that result in different answers.

Comment: Yes, it would work with any divisor, but the error will be larger for larger divisors (as there are less divisible numbers and missing one means relatively larger error). Rounding should give smaller chance of error, flooring will not always be correct. Example: every third number is divisible so it's about 3,3... numbers out of every ten but there are sometimes 4 numbers divisible in some ranges like 30-39.

Comment: The relative error will be smaller for larger intervals as there is only off-by-one error possible for each interval.

Answer (score 7):

There are four possibilities for the first digit $d$:

- $d = 2$: 3333 possibilities, ranging from 20001 to 29997
- $d = 4$: 3333 possibilities, ranging from 40002 to 49998
- $d = 6$: 3334 possibilities, ranging from 60000 to 69999
- $d = 8$: 3333 possibilities, ranging from 80001 to 89997

As such, the number of five-digit numbers which start with an even digit and are divisible by 3, equals:

$$3333 + 3333 + 3334 + 3333 = 13333$$

This result can be verified with the following Python script:

```
i = 0
for a in range(10000, 100000):
  if a // 10000 % 2 == a % 3 == 0:
    i += 1
print(i)
```

Answer (score 4):

There are $3333$ numbers each between $0001$ and $9999$ having remainder $0$, $1$, or $2$ modulo $3$, and $0000$ has remainder $0$. On the other hand, $2$ and $8$ have remainder $2$, whereas $4$ has remainder $1$, and $6$ has remainder $0$. It follows that the number $N$ asked for is given by
$$N=(2+1)\cdot3333+1\cdot3334=13\,333\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

As you say, 1 out of 3 numbers have this property.

If it starts with a $2$, the first is $20001$ and the last one $29997$. This means $\lfloor\frac{29997-20001}{3}\rfloor=3332$ However, doing like this, we forget one number. So, in addition, yo have 3333 numbers (the same for all $n mod 3=2$).

If it starts with a $4$ is $40002$ and the last one $49998$. This means you have $\lfloor\frac{49998-40002}{3}\rfloor=3332$ numbers. However, doing like this, we forget one number. So, in addition, yo have 3333 numbers (the same way all $n mod 3=1$).

If it starts with a $6$, the first is $60000$ and the last one $69999$. This means you have $\lfloor\frac{69999-60000}{3}\rfloor=3333$ However, doing like this, we forget one number. So, in addition, yo have 3334 numbers (the same for all $n mod 3=0$).

Now, just add